# Function not accepting given parameters that matches definition

Tags: swift

I have a swift function, let's call it `functionMakingMeUnhappy`. `functionMakingMeUnhappy` returns a type `T` where `T` is of `SomeProtocol` type.

The definition goes like this:

```
func functionMakingMeUnhappy<T:SomeProtocol>(meta: Metadata, value: Any, name: String) -> T
{
    // Do some stuff and then return something as! T
    return returnSomeStuff(meta, value: value, name: name) as! T
}
```

If it is of any use, Metadata is a structure that looks like this:

```
public struct Metadata
{
    var someUniqueIdentifier: String
    var someOtherUniqueIdentifier: String
    var someTypeIdentifier: String
    var somePermission: String

    var someOtherProperties = [String: Any]()

    init(someUniqueIdentifier: String, 
         someOtherUniqueIdentifier: String, 
         someTypeIdentifier: String, 
         somePermission: String, 
         someOtherProperties: [String: AnyObject])
    {
        self.someUniqueIdentifier = someUniqueIdentifier
        self.someOtherUniqueIdentifier = someOtherUniqueIdentifier
        self.someTypeIdentifier = someTypeIdentifier
        self.somePermission = somePermission
        self.someOtherProperties = someOtherProperties
    }
}
```

Now, my problem, as stupid as it might sound, is that when I call `functionMakingMeUnhappy` with the exact same parameters type as the function definition, I get an error that says **Cannot invoke functionMakingMeUnhappy with an argument list of type '(Metadata, value: Any, name: String)'**

The call is the following:

```
var data = Metadata(someUniqueIdentifier: "id", 
    someOtherUniqueIdentifier: "charType", 
    someTypeIdentifier: "type", 
    somePermission: "readonly", 
    someOtherProperties: [:]
)
var unhappy = functionMakingMeUnhappy(data, value: "someValue", name: "someName")
```

Is there any requirements when having a generic function that could be the cause of this error ?

Comment: How is T supposed to get resolved? (And, following up on that thought, why is this a generic at all?)

Comment: @matt Because it was the work around that I found about "Protocol can only be used as generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"

Comment: Are you still thinking about my question? How is T supposed to get resolved?

Comment: Since every calls returning are of type A, where A is of type T, where type T is of type SomeProtocol, my assumption is that it should be resolved as SomeProtocol

Comment: You need to understand this isn’t a “workaround” and that `T` is _not_ of type `SomeProtocol`.  There is no such physical thing as a `SomeProtocol`.  Only types that _conform_ to that protocol. When you define a function `f<T: SomeProtocol>(t: T)`, `T` is not of type `SomeProtocol`. `T` is any type the conforms to that protocol.  This is very different.

Comment: @Airspeed Velocity So the proper way to fix it would be to go back to a return type of SomeProtocol and handle the first error I had with the protocol itself?

Comment: That depends on what `SomeProtocol` is, and why you put an associated type or `Self` in it originally.

Comment: SomeProtocol comes from an external library and I have little to no control over it

Comment: And (sorry to pile on like this) please note that you completely omitted all of that very important info from your question. If SomeProtocol is itself a generic, you needed to state that. In fact perhaps you just asked the wrong question; if you don't know what "Protocol can only be used as generic constraint" is about, maybe that should have been your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you don't understand what a generic is. Despite the name, generics are not generic - they are not some kind of magic catch-all. On the contrary, a generic is a type that must be known *specifically at compile time*. This is called *resolution* (or *specification*).

Well, you are not doing anything in your call to `functionMakingMeUnhappy` that would resolve the generic. Consider the following very simplified version of your code:

```
protocol P{}
class C:P{}
func f<T:P>() -> T {
    return C() as! T
}
var v = f() // error
```

There is nothing about the call to `f()` that would tell the compiler what T is. Therefore it doesn't compile. I grant that the error message is misleading, but that fact is the *source* of the error. T appears only as the return type. But you are not saying anything about the return type.

Now do it this way:

```
protocol P{}
class C:P{}
func f<T:P>() -> T {
    return C() as! T
}
var v : C = f() // ok
```

That compiles. Why? Because now we have done something to tell the compiler what the return type of `f` will be. Thus T is resolved.

(And please note that I'm not even touching your bizarre claims as to *why* you have made the function a generic. I'm just answering the direct question you asked, namely, why your code, as shown, doesn't compile.)

Comment: The only reason the generic was used is because I wanted a way to return SomeProtocol. Since I have no control over SomeProtocol implementation, fixing the first error "Protocol can only be used as generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" was my initial concern

Comment: Yes, but see my comments above. If that's the problem, you should have _asked_ about that. Instead, you asked about this - and I told you the answer. I have explained the source of the compile error. The fact that you've gone down the wrong road entirely is a different matter.

Comment: Your time is well appreciated, you answered correctly based on the information I provided. Will try to be more specific next time.